# How do I get the live paint bucket not to modify my brush line?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I drew a splinter with multiple lines and joined them.  Now I'm trying to add white as the background color with the paint bucket but it changes my brush line effect. Help ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adjusting the Paint Bucket options?

[image: Paint Bucket Options]

You can get to these options by double clicking the Paint Bucket tool in the panel, or just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after selecting the Paint Bucket tool.